# Revit files without section box on 3D views has to big orbit to rotate after translation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I would like to report a problem with translating revit files(or viewer behavior) and it is happening maybe since the very beginning. I do not know how size of orbit (or something that defines point of rotation and rotation diameter) is internally determined, but what I know is that very often 3D views has to big orbit to rotate and point of rotation is placed outside model area, so when starting rotating a model it is instantly gone in space out of viewer area. Such model is practically unusable. This is possible to prevent when section box is ticked in revit 3D view properties (which I believe sets tight bounding box around model area and rotating point into the center of bounding box), **BUT when you have large complex model from real architect with many references and many views it is not exactly OK to have to open each file and set it for all eg. 200 3D views inside the files**.

In case of uploading file through web interface there is also no possibility of changing view properties using some revit plugin (even there I do not know how would I properly calculate appropriate bounding box for a section box to fit all, including referenced elements) and since there is no Revit.IO neither batch section box plugin yet I believe that something should be made about this. Once a model is translated without section box and rotation behavior is as described (small single models does not necessarily have this issue) - time, one upload and one translation is lost and for no good (and even more disappointing after charging will really begin).

So my **question is if there is a chance that Autodesk could implement some king of auto-section-box feature for 3D views that hasn't set any into their translater or do anything else that would have same result in the viewer?**

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'll forward to my development team. Is it possible to do a quick video with the issue? I believe you have my contact. Thanks again!

Comment: Of, course. Tomorrow I'll make one. Thank you.

Comment: thanks I got the video, we're investigating it now.

Comment: Any progress on that? It's taking guite long..

Comment: Sorry the delay, when you open this model, at the browser console, type: NOP_VIEWER.autocam.pivot and check the coordinates. We're suspecting one of them are either too big or too small comparing to the others.

Comment: I do not have those models any more, because I could not wait for 14 days under active development so I had to reupload them with section boxes. However this issue is not truly fixed by doing so. I can send you model in revit which behaves as described so you can check whatever you need to check?

Comment: please send the file. The console command was a way to help debug it.

Comment: sorry to say, I am unable to reproduce same issue again since original models have been already modified and removing section box from view probably leaves newly created bounding box somehow in the file(so next time they are used anyway) or something changed in translating engine / viewer I do not know.